# iOS - Drawing efficiency (update on slider change)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cgcontext

I am colouring an image on iOS. I am using a slider to select the colour.

When I have "Update Events" on the slider set to continuous, the function that gets called is getting called a lot (the slider goes from 0 to 1535) and so the user interface isn't very responsive.

Is there a way I can make the following code more efficient? I realise I'm starting a new drawing context every time I call the function - can I "save" this context and re-use it?

Thanks in advance.

```
- (IBAction)bodyColourChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
// get the UIColor from self.colourArray
UIColor *color = [self.colourArray objectAtIndex:sender.value];

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"body.png"];

// Begin a new image context to draw the coloured image onto
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bodyView.image.size);

// Get a reference to the context we created
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Set the fill colour
//[[UIColor colorWithRed:color.CGColor green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0] setFill];
[color setFill];

// translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bodyView.image.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

// set the blend mode and the original image
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeOverlay);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bodyView.image.size.width, self.bodyView.image.size.height);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, myImage.CGImage);

// Set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw (colour burn) a coloured rectangle
CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.bodyView.image.CGImage);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);

// Generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
UIImage *colouredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.bodyView.image = colouredImage;
}
```

EDIT: The image I'm colouring is quite large. It's 1541 x 2000 pixels because I want to be able to zoom in without loss of quality. Maybe this is the issue. I'll keep tinkering to see what I can find out.

Comment: Have you tried the CATiledLayer?

Comment: You're right that the image size is a factor, you are right up against the limit of image size without, as David suggests, tiling it. Do you need to have zoom functionality while changing the colour? Could you make a smaller copy, preview the colour change on that then once the user has finished apply the change to the larger image, maybe in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your colouring method, but I've got around a similar performance issue with a slider by only calling the performance-intensive method after a small delay (i.e. the user has paused sliding).

Create some class variables/properties to hold your time related objects:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *sliderValueChangedDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *sliderValueChangedTimer;
```

In your method hooked up to the `UISlider` event:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender {
    // Save the time the slider was changed.
    self.sliderValueChangedDate = [NSDate date];
    // Start a timer if it's not already running.
    if (!self.sliderValueChangedTimer) {
        self.sliderValueChangedTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(checkIfImageShouldBeColoured:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}
```

Then in your `checkIfImageShouldBeColoured:` method you can see if the value has changed in the interim:

```
- (void)checkIfImageShouldBeColoured:(NSTimer *)timer {
    // Get how long has been elapsed since the slider was last changed.
    NSTimeInterval elapsed = -[self.sliderValueChangedDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    // If this is over our threshold, then perform the intensive method.
    if (elapsed > 0.3) {
        [self.sliderValueChangedTimer invalidate];
        self.sliderValueChangedTimer = nil;
        [self changeBodyColour];
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly you are going to schedule _a lot_ of timers ;)

Comment: *cough* um, yes. Maybe better to use a single timer and check a timestamp value :)